# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0' when using Gremlin.NET in Azure Functions

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I want to update an Azure CosmosDB Graph from Azure Functions with Gremlin.NET. I'm using 1.0.10 Functions Cli, .NET Framework 4.7.1 and a project with these dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Gremlin.Net" Version="3.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.2.2-beta3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.13" />
```

At submitting the query

```
    var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(
        Settings.GraphEndPoint,
        443,
        enableSsl: true,
        username: "/dbs/" + Settings.GraphDatabaseName + "/colls/" + Settings.GraphName,
        password: Settings.GraphPrimaryKey);

    using (var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer, new GraphSON2Reader(), new GraphSON2Writer(), GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType))
    {
        var resultSet = await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>(graphStatement);
```

I run into this error:

> Exception while executing function: GraphQuery. Gremlin.Net: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

NuGet dependencies diplay System.Reflection.TypeExtensions Version 4.3.0, file version seems to be 4.1.1.0.

What can I do to make it work?

**Observation added:**
When I clone, add Gremlin.NET csproj to my solution and reference it within the solution, I get the same error. However if I change Gremlin.NET Target framework from `.NET Standard 1.3` to `.NET Standard 2.0` I do not get this error. However then the communication with the Gremlin server breaks in `Connection.ReceiveAsync`.

Comment: Can you please check whether this also occurs with Gremlin.Net alone and no other dependencies like the Azure packages? In that case it would really be a bug in Gremlin.Net for which an issue in the TinkerPop issue tracker would be helpful: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TINKERPOP/issues

Comment: Just saw that you already created an issue there moments before I wrote my comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1952

Comment: @ Florian Hockmann I can't reproduce it on my side, but I get the error information `The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected`.

Comment: @FlorianHockmann you are right - I mixed up things. With https://github.com/KaiWalter/TINKERPOP-1952 I get a System.NullReferenceException when trying to e.g. add a Vertex to a CosmosDB Graph

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue, Ensure that you have the required version of the .NET Framework (4.5.1 or above)

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan my solution is on .NET Framework 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Migrated Function App with Gremlin.NET to Azure Functions v2 - the referencing problem does not occur here.